# How to set variable of variable to be replaced during runtime

Tags: python, regex

1 In Normal way：

```
>>version = {"content":"test","com":2}

>>print("%(content)s hello number is %(com).1f"%version)

test hello number is 2.0
```

2 Abnormal way/Question：

In normal way:

```
print("%(content)s hello number is %(com).1f"%version)
```

content would be replaced by test of version.

If content is variable and would be changed during runtime.

pseudo-code：

```
>>version = {"content":"test","com":2}

>>contentvalue  = content|com  
# contentvalue  point to "content" or "com" during time

#How to write contentvalue 
>>print("%( contentvalue )s hello number is %(com).1f"%version)
```

What it supposed to be: 
contentvalue as variable would be changed to content or com during runtime,which also act as variable and then would be changed to test or 2 according to contentvalue runtime value and version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is because of mixing named and unnamed specifiers, you can use the following method:

```
version = { "content": "test", "com": 2 };

contentvalue = version["content"];
print ("%s"%contentvalue + " hello number is %(com).1f"%version)
```

Comment: Dear，
Thanks for your reply! 

How to change "content" to variable? I.e contentvalue = version[variable.toString()] etc.

What I am confused is that
maybe,
contentvalue = version["content"]
or
contentvalue = version["com"]

Comment: Dear
Thanks for your reply!
Pls help to check the comment below

Comment: You can surely use `contentvalue = version[variable];` (`variable` being equal to anything you want it to be as long as the _key_ exists within your `version` variable) and keep the same implementation explained above. It shouldn't be a problem @RUIM

Comment: Dear IFebles @IFebles 
Thanks for your reply!
I have show code above,but it fails.

Comment: Can you show me exactly how are you trying to do it? So I have a visual example

Comment: Dear IFebles,
Thanks a lot! It's ok now! Appreciate for your help! Wish u have a better life! Would you mind to share your facebook and wechat? Thanks!